# Missing tooltip for Stack Overflow Careers in footer

Tags: feature-request, jobs, tooltips, footer

All sites in the footer have a tooltip with a short description of the site. All good.

However, Stack Overflow Careers is present in the footer without a tooltip. Can such a tooltip please be added? From its [About page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/about), such tooltip might do the job:

> matches great programmers on Stack Overflow with great jobs

Comment: This feature-request is obsolete; none of the links under 'Company' (including 'Hire a Developer') have tooltips now.

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks for closing! (Guess you don't get such positive feedback for closing question a lot ;))

Comment: No, that's rare. You're welcome!